# cx_Freeze: Executable with pytesseract fails on other PC

Tags: python, executable, cx-freeze, python-tesseract

I've made an executable file from my Python - OCR program (`import pytesseract`) using cx_Freeze. The resulting .exe works fine on my own machine. To test the program I made a zip-folder and shared it with some friends and colleagues on a share point.
Now there is the following problem with the executable. It seems like pytesseract isn't included in the executable / zip-folder.

Here is the ErrorLog:

```
The file is not a PNG-file:  20181108 Kontaktanzeigen-Er_sucht_sie.jpg
The file is not a PNG-file:  20181108 Kontaktanzeigen-Sie_sucht_ihn.jpg
The file is not a PNG-file:  20181108 Language family tree.jpg
The file is not a PNG-file:  20181108 relax.jpg
The file is not a PNG-file:  20181109 Essen wie Gott am Südpol S1.JPG
The file is not a PNG-file:  20181109 Fahrzeugschein1.jpg
The file is not a PNG-file:  20181112 sie_sind_alle_so_dumm.jpg
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 170, in run_tesseract
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 992, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
  File "C:\Users\TFischer\PycharmProjects\Test_Project\OCR.py", line 67, in img_to_text
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 294, in image_to_string
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 202, in run_and_get_output
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 172, in run_tesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path

Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 170, in run_tesseract
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 992, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
  File "C:\Users\TFischer\PycharmProjects\Test_Project\OCR.py", line 73, in img_to_text1
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 294, in image_to_string
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 202, in run_and_get_output
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 172, in run_tesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path
```

The first lines are absolute clear. I've found some ideas to modify `setup.py` to include all imports in the executable created by cx_Freeze. Here is the latest version.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os.path

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

additional_mods = ['numpy.core._methods', 'numpy.lib.format']
additional_files = [os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
            os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll')]

options = {
    'build_exe': {'include_files': additional_files, 'includes': additional_mods}
    }

setup(options = options,
      name = "main" ,
      version = "0.1" ,
      description = "" ,
      executables = [Executable("main.py")])
```

Answer (score 2):

`pytesseract` is a wrapper for Google's Tesseract-OCR Engine. In order that `pytesseract`works, the Tesseract-OCR engine needs to be installed and one must be able to invoke the tesseract command as `tesseract` (this means that the Tesseract-OCR installation directory needs to be in the PATH).

I believe that `pytesseract` has been properly included in the executable but that the `tesseract` command does not work on the "other PC" (either Tesseract-OCR is not installed there or the Tesseract-OCR installation directory is not in the PATH there).

You need to tell the owner of the "other PC" to install Tesseract-OCR and to check that it can be started with the command `tesseract` from any location.

Another option would be to include the whole Tesseract-OCR installation directory in the frozen executable using the `build_exe`option `include_files` (your variable `additional_files`) and to make sure that this included directory gets included in the PATH on the target PC, but this is probably not platform-independent and thus not recommended.

Comment: Since I want give the zip-Folder and some .png Files to students I want to keep it as simple as possible. I think I'll try the second idea.
So if they put the unzipped file in `C:\OCR` they must add `C:\OCR` to their environmental variables or do they need to add the exact path to the sub-folder `C:\OCR\build\...\tesseract`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to add the exact path to the sub-folder in which `tesseract.exe` is found. You might even manage to do it dynamically in your main application using `os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + path_to_tesseract_folder` with `path_to_tesseract_folder` computed on the basis of the main application location at runtime.

Comment: I'm currently testing the changes. When I have results I'll let you know how it worked for me.