# Executable file created with cx_Freeze crashes on windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, cx-freeze

I am trying to make an executable using cx_Freeze, it creates the exe, but whenever I try to launch it crashes with some error (see below).

`setup.py`:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import glob
import os
import zlib
import shutil

base = None
# PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\tcl\\tk8.6"
os.environ['TESSERACT_LIBRARY'] = "E:\\Tesseract-OCR"

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

if sys.platform == 'win64':
    base = "Win64GUI"

include = [ 'jinja2', 'jinja2.ext',] #Include packages

includefiles = ['gui/']

options = {'build_exe':{'includes':include,'include_files': includefiles}}   

flaskapp = Executable(script="scan_config.py",
                       targetName="D2D.exe",
                   )

setup(
    name="D2D",
    version="1.0",
    author="abc",
    description="D2d",
    options={
        'build_exe': {
            'include_files': includefiles,
            'includes': include,
            'build_exe': "build"
        }
    },
    executables=[flaskapp]
)
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "scan_config.py", line 5, in 
>     File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask__init__.py", line 14, in  from jinja2 import escape
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2__init__.py", line 82, in  _patch_async()
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2__init__.py", line 78, in _patch_async from jinja2.asyncsupport import patch_all
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\asyncsupport.py", line 13, in  import asyncio
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio__init__.py", line 8, in  from .base_events import *
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 37, in  from . import constants
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from 'asyncio' (E:\engine\build\lib\asyncio__init__.pyc)

P.S. I tried PyInstaller also, but I don't know how to include pytesseract.

Comment: Try to start your executable from a cmd prompt to maybe get some error message. If you get any, please add it to your question (as text, not as image).

Comment: Thank you. Edited

Comment: As far as tesseract is concerned: see [cx_Freeze: Executable with pytesseract fails on other PC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53514311/8516269) for a discussion of the inclusion in cx_Freeze (without accepted answer yet).

Comment: So as per your ans I included the tesseract folder and path in the code. After building exe, i am able to see tesseract library. But the error is regarding jinja2, which is part of flask. I am running it on my own laptop. So there are less chances of tesseract error.

Comment: Try to add `'packages': packages` to the `build_exe` dictionary with `packages = ['asyncio']`

Comment: If this still does not work, try to move `'jinja2'` from the `includes`list to the `packages` list.

Comment: @jpeg I have multiple files, calling them from `main.py` (e.g import abc) , & added the file names in `includefiles:['abc.py'] in setup.py`. After running the exe it is not able to call other py files. App freezes in mid way only

Comment: If you explicitly `import abc` in `main.py`, you should not need to add `'abc.py'` to the `include_files` option list in `setup.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downgraded the python version to 3.6. That solved most of the errors. For jinja2 I did `pip install https://github.com/pallets/jinja/zipball/master`, and also included the `mkl` & `libiomp5md` files. In the multiprocessing folder I changed `Pool.pyc` to `pool.pyc`