# Cx-freeze: Python program compiled into .exe and Pytesseract doesn't work on other users pc

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze, python-tesseract

So I managed to compile my program into a .exe file with 'cx-freeze' and everything runs perfectly fine besides the functions that use Pytesseract.
I know that the error is because you're required to set your Pytesseract path as I do here:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract'
```

I know a simple fix is to have the user download and install pytesseract OCR but thats not an efficient solution, surely there's a way to fix it.

Setup.py I used to compile into a .exe using cx-freeze:

````
# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["tkinter","sys","pynput","time","pyautogui","PIL","os","win32api","win32con","cv2","pyperclip","pytesseract","numpy","threading","mysql.connector"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = "Win32GUI"  # <- no command line will appear

target = Executable(
script="MatrixARKBot.py", 
base=base,
targetName="MatrixARKBot.exe") 

setup(  name = "MatrixARKBot.py",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "Matrix ARK Bot",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [target])
    ```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cx\_Freeze: Executable with pytesseract fails on other PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53514311/cx-freeze-executable-with-pytesseract-fails-on-other-pc)